# How can i cancel a download in firefox by using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to download about 500 files from a website. It works but sometimes that web doesn't work well and the download doesn't finish. I cancel it manually but I want to do it in my script.

Is there any way to do it with the Selenium API in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium downloads are not cancellable because a download can either occur in the background (where there is no javascript on the current page that can interact with it) or it can replace the current page (where there will be no javascript at all).

Instead you can collect the URLs you wish to download by inspecting the links you are about to click but not clicking on them in selenium. If you then request them using a regular Java request you can handle them appropriately (i.e. add a timeout). You may need to collect the cookies from Selenium in order to make the download request.

You can get the cookies like this:

```
webdriver.manage().getCookies()
```

See [the documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#getCookies%28%29).

You can get the URL for a link like this:

```
webdriver.findElement(...).getAttribute("href");
```

You may have to turn this from a relative URL into an absolute URL.

You can then make the request in Java like this:

```
URL url = new URL(...);
URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
StringBuilder cookies = new StringBuilder();

for (Cookie cookie : webdriver.manage().getCookies()) {
    if (cookies.length() > 0) {
        cookies.append("; ");
    }
    cookies.append(cookie.getName())
        .append("=")
        .append(cookie.getValue());
}
request.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies.toString());
request.setConnectionTimeout(...);
request.setReadTimeout(...);
request.connect();

request.getInputStream(); // do stuff with the data from the input stream
```